# "Police is" or "police are"?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

I am aware that we alway treat *the police* as singular when we refer to it as social instutution. But what about if are refering to *police* as a group of people who are policemen? For example:

> There **is**/**are** a lot of police around the crime.

Comment: Note that we ***don't*** always treat the police as singular when we refer to it [them!?] as a social institution. Google Books has more hits for [*the police **are** an institution*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+police+are+an+institution%22) than for [*the police **is** an institution*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+police+is+an+institution%22) (where it's only the ***institution*** that's always syntactically singular, not the ***police***).

Answer (score -1):

The police were informed about the matter. 
It is a collective noun like "cattle" and takes a plural verb.

Comment: "La police vous parle" - song by Mickey 3d (not relevant really).